# how best to run large VBA loops in MS Access without freezing

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have an access DB with [for the sake of simplifying this question] one table. That table has 150,000 rows and two fields: `F1` and `F2`. I have a VBA function that pulls a `DAO.Recordset` of the table then it iterates it. Within the loop, I build build a string of `F1.Value` in sets of 200 and then query Active Directory for some data. Then I take that returned data and update `F2` in the table and then the loop continues with the next 200.

This all works fine but it takes a long time and freezes Access. I'm trying to figure out how to make Access not freeze. Ideally I'd like to be able to update the status bar with progress (e.g. batch X of Y).

```
Public Function DoIt()
    Dim nRecordSet As DAO.Recordset
    Dim nRecordSetClone As DAO.Recordset
    Dim nFoundItem As Variant
    Dim nBatchCounter As Integer
    Dim nFilter As String
    Dim nFoundInAD As Collection

    ' to batch AD queries
    nBatchCounter = 0
    nFilter = ""

    ' the data
    Set nRecordSet = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT [F1], [F2] FROM [Table1] WHERE [F2] Is Null")

    ' i clone it so i can move the cursor independent of the previous one
    Set nRecordSetClone = nRecordSet.Clone

    Do Until nRecordSet.EOF
        ' build the query string
        nFilter = nFilter + "(name=" & nRecordSet.Fields("F1").Value & ")"

        ' increment counter
        nBatchCounter = nBatchCounter + 1

        ' move the cursor to the next record
        nRecordSet.MoveNext

        ' check if I have a full batch or I am at the end of my records
        If nBatchCounter = 200 Or nRecordSet.EOF Then
            ' search AD
            ' nQueryAD.Query is a module.function I have to query AD using LDAP
            ' it returns a Collection of results
            ' this function can take time but it usually returns instantly
            Set nFoundInAD = nQueryAD.Query("(&(ObjectCategory=computer)(|" & nFilter & "))", "distinguishedName,name")

            ' make sure we actually found something
            If Not nFoundInAD Is Nothing Then
                If nFoundInAD.Count Then
                    ' iterate through each found
                    For Each nFoundItem In nFoundInAD

                        ' find the matching record in the clone and update it
                        nRecordSetClone.FindFirst "[F1] = '" & nFoundItem.Item("name") & "'"
                        nRecordSetClone.Edit
                        nRecordSetClone.Fields("F2").Value = nFoundItem.Item("distinguishedName")
                        nRecordSetClone.Update
                    Next nFoundItem
                End If
            End If

            ' reset batch stuff
            nBatchCounter = 0
            nFilter = ""
        End If
    Loop

    nRecordSetClone.Close
    nRecordSet.Close
    Set nRecordSet = Nothing
    Set nRecordSetClone = Nothing
    Set nFoundInAD = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: I fear MS-Access doesn't support multi-threading, you cannot avoid the application freezing if the code is still running. You might want to optimize it a bit.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845770%28v=office.15%29.aspx

Comment: @MatteoNNZ: Any advice/recommendations on how to optimize?

Comment: @GordThompson: Thanks. I know how to update the status bar but the problem is that after so many iterations Access freezes and the status bar updates won't show anything until the function is done.

Comment: If your code works but just needs some tips to be optimized, [our parallel community called "Code Review"](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is the place you're looking for.

Comment: Have you tried putting a [DoEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262728%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) statement in the loop?

Comment: @MatteoNNZ that's correct, but this question *as it is* would be rejected as hypothetical code.

Comment: @RubberDuck: Why hypothetical? I'm using it right now. Granted I renamed somethings but the code does work.

Comment: @GordThompson: Where in the function would I put it? I was having trouble figuring that out.

Comment: First decide where in the code you want to use `SysCmd acSysCmdSetStatus` to display your message in the status bar.  Then call `DoEvents` on the next line so your code will yield control to Windows and allow it to update the screen.

Comment: On CR, we ask that you post your real code because a good review will talk about algoritm right along side your naming and style. You *might* get away with this one there, but I'm not sure. Please do visit our help center before posting there.

Comment: We also don't help with implementing new features, so adding a status bar would be off topic.

Comment: @rubberduck alright, didnt know this, actually i dont know well the community (i only have an unanswered question that has been migrated from here). Thanks for the clarification

Comment: @RubberDuck: Thanks. I don't really need help with the status bar as I've figured that part out. The issue is that the large VBA loop freezes Access so it doesn't update. Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at using ADO instead of DAO?  You can execute the query asynchronously using the ADODB command object and the adAsyncExecute option.